# UITableView DataSource Calling sequence Changed In IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

In Ios 8 calling sequence of TableView Datasource methods are changed.Due to this I have faced many problems like calulating height in cellForRowAtIndexPath not woking correctly for me.

### In ios 8 it will call like :

- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.655 testTable[2861:49611] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.658 testTable[2861:49611] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.659 testTable[2861:49611] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.664 testTable[2861:49611] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.665 testTable[2861:49611] cellfor row
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.668 testTable[2861:49611] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.669 testTable[2861:49611] cellfor row
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.669 testTable[2861:49611] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:23:09.670 testTable[2861:49611] cellfor row

**Cell for height again called with cell for row.**

### Before Ios 8 Calling sequence was:

- 2014-09-29 12:37:33.786 testTable[3281:60b] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:37:33.788 testTable[3281:60b] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:37:33.789 testTable[3281:60b] Height
- 2014-09-29 12:37:33.794 testTable[3281:60b] cellfor row
- 2014-09-29 12:37:33.796 testTable[3281:60b] cellfor row
- 2014-09-29 12:37:33.803 testTable[3281:60b] cellfor row

**Is any one else faced the same problem ?**

Comment: yes Correct , I am also facing the same Problem, but apple doesn't documented this anywhere . Its Strange.

Comment: @ManiaChamp : True , There is no documentation I found yet, Is any one else find anything regarding this.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but there is a `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method that you can also implement.